# RadiobuttonFor and nullable bool checked property issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I have a MVC View Model in which I have nullable boolean property:

```
[DisplayName("Is Active")]
public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)</label>
    </div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsActive, true, new {id = "IsIsActiveTrue" })
    <label>Yes</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsActive, false, new {id = "IsIsActiveFalse" })
    <label>No</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new {id = "IsIsActiveAll"})
    <label>All</label>
</div>
```

By default, I would like to select All when page loads. I tried to add

> @checked = "checked"

but it didn't work (any of radiobutton value is selected). Please advise.

Comment: What does "All" mean for an Yes or No question ? Q : "Do you own pets ?Yes or No". Answer:"All" . ????

Comment: "All" means that I want to return all records ("Active" and "Inactive").

Comment: IMHO, 2 check boxes would be more appropriate here

Comment: @Shyju can you please put your solution as answer?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass `NULL` as the value for the radio button when using `RadioButtonFor` helper method. If you pass `""`as the value, you cannot set that in your GET action as your variable type is `bool?`,not string.

If you absolutely want 3 radiobuttons with your current type, you may simply write pure HTML code to render that. As long as your radio button's `name` attribute value matches your view model property name, model binding will work fine when you submit the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Customer"))
{
    <label>Active</label>
    <input type="radio" name="IsActive" value="true"/>

    <label>In Active</label>
    <input type="radio" name="IsActive" value="false"/>

    <label>All</label>
    <input type="radio" name="IsActive" checked="checked" />

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Here we are setting the `checked` attribute for all in the HTML markup.

Another option is to switch your controls from 3 radio buttons to 2 checkboxes. You can mark all of them checked initially and user may select/unselect as needed. Another option is changing your type from `bool?` to an enum with these 3 values. With both of these approaches, with the use of `CheckBoxFor` or `RadioButtonFor` helper, you should be able to set the items which needs to be checked, in your GET action method. Use the one which is more appropriate to your code structure/style.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by replacing RadiobuttonFor with RadioButton:

```
        <div class="row">
            <label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            @Html.RadioButton("IsActive", true, false) Yes
            @Html.RadioButton("IsActive", false, false) No
            @Html.RadioButton("IsActive", null, true) All
        </div>
```

Comment: when I tried this I get a runtime error: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value'